# Increasing the maximum angle of laser scanners with optics?

Tags: optics, laser

With laser scanning devices, very roughly speaking, the maximum deflection angle seems to be inversly proportional to speed. So for example, while acousto-optic deflectors can steer the beam very quickly, they can only do so over a small angle. As I understand it, this situation is roughly analogous to electrostatic vs magnetic CRTs. Electrostatic tubes are much faster (thus their use in old analog scopes), but they also work over a much smaller angle and so have to be very long.

The idea that occurred is whether it would be possible to use optics, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97oJm.png to "magnify" the maximum angle that can be scanned with something like an acousto-optic deflector. The problem is, essentially, wouldn't you end up with something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6KY8.png ? So, basically, is there anyway to increase the angle of laser beams from a scanner without also compensatingly increasing the divergence of the beam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider an afocal teleconverter:

[image: Afocal teleconverter]

It is composed of two lenses, with a coincident focal plane. This will *multiply* the beam angle by some factor, keeping the beam parallelism. It is somewhat similar to the principle of binoculars.

Comment: Wow thank you, that looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for.